# Run a testsuite in multiple environment

Tags: spring, junit, applicationcontext

I want to run my test suite in multiple environment like below:

ApplicationContextTest.class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/application-context.xml")
public class MyTest{

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Test
public void test1() {
    ((ConfigurableEnvironment)applicationContext.getEnvironment()).setActiveProfiles("env1");
    ((GenericXmlApplicationContext)applicationContext).refresh();
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    ((ConfigurableEnvironment)applicationContext.getEnvironment()).setActiveProfiles("env2");
    ((GenericXmlApplicationContext)applicationContext).refresh();
}
```

}

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<beans profile="env1">

</beans>

<beans profile="env2">

</beans>
```

When I run test, I got an exception

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once`

Are there any ways to set Active Profile after ApplicationContext started up?

Or Any solution to solve above exception?

Thanks.

Comment: No one can help me in this problem ? So sad :(

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to choose one or more specific profile(s) is to set a system property when running the tests

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=env1
```

You can also set one or more profile(s) as default with the system property

```
-Dspring.profiles.default=env1
```

I normally do this in a static init method of my test

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    // set default spring test profile
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.default", "default");
}
```

You will find some information if you search for these properties (If you need a Spring code reference you have to look at the [AbstractEnvironment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html) class).

I do not know of any way how to change the profile after startup. In this case you may have to use a new JVM on each test (can e.g. be done by the maven surefire plugin using the [reuseForks](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reuseForks) setting). Or even better place the tests that use the same profile in the same test class and set the profile as needed.

IMHO a test should not depend on a specific profile. A test should pass - whatever profile is used. Than you can easily change e.g. between test (mock) or 'real' environments.